# Twig Error after Symfony 2.7 Upgrade: "The "native_profiler" extension is not enabled

Tags: symfony, phpunit, twig

After A `Symfony` Upgrade, `composer.json`

- "symfony/symfony": "2.4.*",
- "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",

I get a Error while running `phpunit` tests. In env `dev` and `prod` everything works fine.

log output:

```
   request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "The native_profiler" extension is not enabled in "@WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar_js.html.twig"
```

Comment: It would probably make the question easier to answer if a stack trace was also posted. Did you also try clearing the cache (i.e. `rm -rf app/cache/test/*`)?

Comment: yes, i tried to delete the caches, still the same. Went back to 2.4 an everything is fine.

Answer (score 6):

The twig native profile extension is turned on automatically if the debug mode is on and turned off if the debug mode is off in Symfony 2.7. So if you warming up the cache with debug mode on the twig templates are rendered with the profiler enabled.
But if a test runs with debug off (for example Kris Wallsmith solution is used) the extension is disabled in the tests (but still enabled in pre-rendered templates), that cause the error.
Solution: before running tests clear the cache with debug mode off.

> app/console cache:clear --env=test --no-debug

The cache will be cleared and warmed up without the twig profiler.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today, but slightly different. At the end I found out, that the TwigProfiler is enabled in debug-mode automatically.
In KernelTestCase.php I found:

```
isset($options['debug']) ? $options['debug'] : true
```

So in my TestCases I added the option 'debug' => false and it worked again.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error on our jenkins. Our CI job runs (1) PHPUnit tests, than (2) functional tests with LiipFunctionalTestBundle and at the end (3) protractor tests.

The twig templates were compiled by the functional tests (2) which configures the kernel to be in debug mode. The Protractor tests however start a PHP server in test env but not in debug mode. So the twig templates were not compatible. I solved the problem by deleting the cache between step (2) and (3).

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the cache after changing debug mode appears to have solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `--no-debug` switch also when generating javascript translation files with `bazinga:js-translation:dump`

For example like this command

```
../app/console bazinga:js-translation:dump -vvv --no-debug -e stage
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating version. It helped for me from version **1.18** to **1.24**.

Using Symfony 2.7 with Sylius 0.13

More info:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15318
https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/pull/1824